# node.js websocket, converting JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, push-api

with node.js I run this code:

```
var autobahn = require('autobahn');
var wsuri = "wss://api.poloniex.com";
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
  url: wsuri,
  realm: "realm1"
});

connection.onopen = function (session) {
        function marketEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        function tickerEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        function trollboxEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        session.subscribe('USDT_BTC', marketEvent);

}

connection.onclose = function () {
  console.log("Websocket connection closed");
}

connection.open();
```

and reseve via push-API JSON-Data:

```
[ { type: 'orderBookModify',
    data: { type: 'bid', rate: '2357.77000002', amount: '0.82956965' } } ]
```

now I want to work with the data, is it possible to store it into mysql or declare a variable with just a sequence of the JSON-Array?

Comment: `is it possible to store it into mysql`: yes. `declare a variable with just a sequence of the JSON-Array` not sure what you mean with `a sequence of JSON-Array`

Comment: I want to catch just the rate in one varibale and the amount on another

Comment: Use JSON.parse for this.

Comment: [ { type: 'orderBookModify',
    data: { type: 'bid', rate: '2357.77000002', amount: '0.82956965' } } ] is it a json-array or string?

Comment: Both, json is just string data in a specific format

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/1caw7L91/

Comment: I added         `function marketEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
                var test = JSON.parse(args);
                console.log(test[0].test.rate);` but it doesn't work

Comment: What does not work? Does it give any errors? Maybe args is already a JSON string and you don't need to `JSON.parse` it

Comment: you are right `var data = args; console.log(data[0].data.rate);` is the soulution. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON.stringify to convert the JSON into string and then save it into MySQL. However, I am not sure about what you meant by a sequence of the JSON-Array